# Sonar looks for artifacts in wrong maven repository

Tags: maven, hudson, jenkins, sonarqube

I have a Jenkins job running Maven on master machine

I've added a post build step to run Sonar and pointed it to the project's `pom.xml`.

The problem is that Jenkins build runs on master, and Sonar server is running on different machine. So when the build finishes, Sonar looks for the build artifacts in the repository where it's installed instead of the master machine where Jenkins ran Maven.

Is there a workaround other then installing both Sonar and Jenkins on the same machine ?

More Details:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project server-api: Could not resolve dependencies for project frm:frm-server-api:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find frm:frm-model:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in http://DIFFERENT_SERVER:7080/nexus/content/repositories/releases/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of releases has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

The `DIFFERENT_SERVER` is a server not related to `sonar` server or `Jenkins` server, We are using it but not in the context of this project so i don't really know how it got there. I am guessing this is configuration error. more details:

1. The Jenkins job type is a general project and not a pure maven job.
2. I am using the `sonar` jenkins plugin as post build trigger and specifying the `pom.xml` i'm using.
3. I have configured `settings.xml` in `MAVEN_HOME/conf` with the required details.

Comment: the sonar server does not look for the artifactes, the sonar:sonar maven task does. the sonar server just saves the results.

Comment: @oers and the sonar:sonar maven task runs in Jenkins server or is it running on Sonar's ?

Comment: it runs locally on your jenkins server

Answer (score 2):

The fact that Sonar server is running on a different machine is definitely not a problem for launching an analysis, and you shouldn't have any problem running a Sonar analysis from your Jenkins master, may the Sonar DB and/or the Sonar Server be on different machines.

You just have to make sure that the configuration on your Jenkins (= Sonar properties) + the configuration of your machine (= potential firewall) allows the Sonar batch to:

1. Query the Sonar Web server URLs
2. Query the configured database

Comment: Thanks, this must be a configuration error I guess, i've added more info in my question

Comment: I've added the necessary profile to `settings.xml` do I also need to add anything to my `pom.xml` ? it seems like it doesn't take the `sonar` configuration i've added to the settings file

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that i didn't add anything to my project's `pom.xml` and also i have been using maven up to `package` phase where Sonar requires to `install` the artifacts in the maven repository as well so it could use them later.

So I ran maven with `mvn clean install -DskipTests=true` and later used the Sonar post build step.